# MongoDB aggregate join two $group

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model that looks like this:

```
{
tokens: [
{
  value: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  origin: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Unknown',
  },
  grabbedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
},
], ...
}
```

Now I want to format the data in the following way that all "tokens" with a date of the past 12 days are returned and grouped by their origin with a count per day.

So the result would look like this: `[{ origin: 'Unknown', data: [0,1,2,...] }, { origin: 'origin2', data: [1,10,...] }]`
The data array would hold the count of tokens acquired on past 12 days, beginning with the first day to the 12th day.

I already tried something like this:

```
Account.aggregate([
{ $unwind: '$tokens' },
{ $match: { 'tokens.grabbedAt': { $gte: beforeDate } } },
{
  $group: {
    _id: { origin: '$tokens.origin', date: '$tokens.grabbedAt' },
    count: { $sum: 1 },
  },
},
{ $project: { _id: 0, origin: '$_id.origin', date: '$_id.date', count: '$count' } },
{ $sort: { date: 1 } },
]);
```

But using this code each date and origin is included multiple times. So how can I "join" or merge these two $groups?

Comment: Show us the o/p you are getting? What is the expected o/p too.

Comment: @Gibbs I already described the wanted output in the question description. But the current output is something like `{ origin 'Unknown', date: 2022-05-15T20:17:43.123Z, count: 1 },
  { origin: 'Unknown' date: 2022-05-15T20:17:46.765Z, count: 1 }, },` But I want to join these two or more entries and make an data array with the count for the days.

Comment: You are already grouping by origin. It cannot be the o/p unless you do unwind after grouping.

Comment: The unwind is done before the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, is `$unwind` and `$group` the tokens by `origin` and then use 3 steps to create a list of the 12 needed dates. Then we can use a `$set` step to create the empty dates objects that were missing. Now we can `$concatArrays` our real measurements with the "artificial" ones of the empty days. The last part is just to group and sum it up.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$tokens"},
  {$match: {"tokens.grabbedAt": {$gte: beforeDate}}},
  {$sort: {"tokens.date": 1}},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$tokens.origin",
      res: {
        $push: {
          dateString: {$dateToString: {date: "$tokens.grabbedAt",
          format: "%Y-%m-%d"}},  count: 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {startDate: beforeDate, range: {$range: [0, 12, 1]}}
  },
  {
    $set: {
      dateStrings: {
        $map: {
          input: "$range",
          in: {
            dateString: {
              $dateToString: {
                date: {
                  $add: [
                    "$startDate",
                    {$multiply: ["$$this", 24, 60, 60, 1000]}
                  ]
                },
                format: "%Y-%m-%d"
              }
            },
            count: 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$project: {data: {$concatArrays: ["$dateStrings", "$res"]}}},
  {$unwind: "$data"},
  {$group: {
      _id: {origin: "$_id",  date: "$data.dateString"},
      count: {$sum: "$data.count"}
    }
  },
  {$group: {_id: "$_id.origin", date: {$push: "$count"}}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PFmWemCPotP)

Comment: If it works for you please accept it, so it will be easier for others to find it.